# Checking if checkboxs is ticked after adding it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

When the page starts the users is asked to selected a category. Once a category is selected with Ajax some checkboxes are loaded.

I need to do something when these checkboxes are ticked however the problem is i cannot detect change on them since i just added them.

*** options variable contains the input checkbox

```
$("#subcat").append(options)
```

I then try to check weither the it is checked or not with the code  below

```
<script>
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        if($(this).attr("checked")) {
            alert("abc");
        } else {
            alert("CBA");
        }
    });
</script>
```

If i add a input check box directly onto the html file then it detects change however when i load checkboxes with ajax it does not.

Comment: I think $(this).prop("checked"); will work

Comment: I think that your problem is similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343991/jquery-cant-bind-event-to-ajax-loaded-element-using-on

Comment: you need to add `.change` listener after you programmatically add checkbox

Comment: EDIT____ I just noticed that when you toggle the checkboxes it does not add the "checked" attribute. Anyone have a fix?

Comment: `code`$("#subcat").on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){ alert(this.checked) });